# Drawing over matplotlib axis/figs: get yticklabel individual position and use it for drawlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I would like to know if someone who dominate more advanced matplotlib could help me in this one. I have a heatmap, which could be simulated with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import string
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

def random_letter(chars=string.ascii_uppercase, size=2):
    char_arr = np.array(list(chars))
    if size > 27:
        size = 27
    np.random.shuffle(char_arr)
    return char_arr[:size]

data = np.random.poisson(1, (174, 40))

y_labels = [', '.join(x for x in random_letter()) for _ in range(174)]
y_labels = sorted(y_labels)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 16.5)

heatmap = ax.pcolor(data, 
                    cmap=plt.cm.Blues, 
                    vmin=data.min(), 
                    vmax=data.max(), 
                    edgecolors='white')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+.5, minor=False);
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+.5, minor=False);
ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(40), rotation=90);
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels, fontsize=5);
cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, shrink=0.33, aspect=10)
```

My need is to draw lines over the heatmap, to separate features over the ytickslabels as I show in the following image (in which i draw by hand):

[image: heatmap with red lines draw over the y tick label when the first letter changes]

Any one knows how to programmatically code matplotlib to do that?

Comment: It's unclear to me how you derive the y values of your horizontal lines; are those related to the yticks?

Comment: I think axhline does what you want.

Comment: `hline` + `clip_on=False` (sorry, don't have time to write a more through answer)

Comment: @tillsten `axhline` is very clever and sets the limits in axes-fraction units so it can't do the off-the-edge part.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the liberty to do write the full solution for @tcaswell, actually it only takes 7 more lines:

```
xl, xh=ax.get_xlim()
left=xl-(xh-xl)*0.1 #10% extension on each side
right=xh+(xh-xl)*0.1
Lines=ax.hlines([5,10,15,20], left, right, color='r', linewidth=1.2)
Lines.set_clip_on(False)
ax.set_xlim((xl, xh))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but who to detect the position where a specific yticklabel finish ? This is the main problem.

Comment: something yticklabel_pos = like ax.yaxis.get_label_position()

Comment: That is actually the easy part, just replace the `[5,10,15,20]` with `[i for i, v in enumerate(y_labels) if v in [a list of THE_TICK_LABELS_YOU_WANT TO DRAW LINES AT]]`